# How to remove PHP $_SESSION with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an array within a PHP Session variable which I need to remove via AJAX.

This is how I do it:

1. HTML:

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="delete_pix(false, '1', false, '1.jpg');">remove</a>`
   ```
2. JavaScript:

   ```
   function delete_pix(id, no, hash, plupload){
   $.post("/remove.php",{ 
       id: id, 
       no: no, 
       h: hash, 
       pl: plupload
   }); 
   }
   ```
3. remove.php

   ```
   unset($_SESSION['files']);
   error_log(print_r($_SESSION, 1).'test');
   ```

Unfortunately this does not work. The file remove.php does not have access to the session. print_r($_SESSION) does not output any values.

Thank you in advance on any help on this.

Comment: are you saying that you want to remove `'superglobal', or automatic global, variable.` ? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Looks like you just forgot session_start

Comment: @llamerr — Looks more like a value in the session array, not the array itself.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and look at your console.

Comment: To answer this question you need to post what $_SESSION['files'] looks like before. Also, as Quentin pointed out, you need session_start().

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I forgot session_start(); inside remove.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your funtion on php you need call the method `session_start();` and later `session_unset($_SESSION['nameOfSession']);` this will erase your session.